# Ubuntu on USB stick with Windows installed

Tags: usb

Can I install Ubuntu on USB stick without touching Windows Hard Drive and boot from USB when needed?

I believe I read you must install 'Boot' stuff on computer main HDD!

It defies the need to have it on USB then.

I am no Ubuntu expert, I am mainly a Windows user!

Answer (score 2):

Simply put yes you can. I keep a 16gb 'live usb' stick on my key chain for that very reason. The only problem that I have ran into is to boot from the USB you have to restart the computer and at some public places the is frowned on.

Comment: OK - thanks, I was actually trying one Stick and it was only 4Gb and 12.04 wanted at least 4.4Gb! My luck - I will get a larger one tomorrow. It is useful when you are somewhere else or repairing a computer.

Comment: Downloading the latest stable version right now and will use Pendrivelinux - thanks

Comment: ok let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space into your PC.

1. Download [Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Yes, I remember now - Pendrivelinux. I did check it out one or 2 years ago and forgot - thank!